# Title: "Google login page shows 'Access denied' error: OAuth 2.0 redirect_uri_mismatch"

Tags: python, flask, authorization, google-oauth, redirect-uri

Body:
I'm implementing Google login functionality in my web application using OAuth 2.0. However, when I click on the Google login button and get redirected to the Google login page, I receive an 'Access denied' error. The error message states: "You can't sign in because this app sent an invalid request. Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch".

Here are the steps I have taken so far:

- I have set up the necessary client ID and client secret in my
  application.
- I have specified the authorized JavaScript origins and
  redirect URIs correctly.
- I have checked the redirect URI in both my
  code and the Google Cloud Console, and they match exactly.

However, I still encounter the `Access denied` error. I have also referred to the Google documentation on handling `redirect_uri_mismatch` errors but haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Can someone please help me identify the cause of this error and suggest a solution? I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights into resolving this issue.

Code Snippet:
[Include relevant code snippets related to the OAuth 2.0 setup and the callback route if applicable.]

Error Message:

> The error message I receive is: "You can't sign in because this app
> sent an invalid request. Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch".

Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

What I have tried:

- I have double-checked the authorized JavaScript origins and redirect URIs in both my code and the Google Cloud Console, ensuring they match.
- I have regenerated the client ID and client secret, updating them in my application.
- I have cleared my browser cache and tried accessing the Google login page again.
- I have referred to the Google documentation on handling redirect_uri_mismatch errors and followed the suggested steps, but the issue persists.

What I was expecting:
I expected that after clicking on the Google login button, I would be redirected to the Google login page and prompted to authorize the application. Upon successful authorization, I should be redirected back to my application with the necessary authorization code or access token.

However, instead of the expected behavior, I am receiving an `Access denied` error with the message:

> "You can't sign in because this app sent an invalid request. Error
> 400: redirect_uri_mismatch".

Based on the steps I have taken and the error message received, I am seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully implement Google login in my web application.

Comment: if this is a coding question, then please post the code or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)